# Add column to a database table named after a text in textbox winform

Tags: c#, sql

I use a textbox to enter the column name that I want, then I pass the "string query" which is:

```
ALTER TABLE itemsTable ADD '" + textbox1.text + "' VARCHAR(50) NULL;
```

I keep getting an error:

> Invalid syntax near "the text I have entered in the textbox"

But if I remove the `'"+textbox1.text+"'` and replace it with `item1`, it works fine

Comment: Does you column name follow your dbms's naming rules?

Comment: i don't know what u mean exactly, but the name is (item1) in the textbox and its the same when  i write it in the query string. it works fine in the second condition only although its the same string in both conditions.

Comment: Hm - I wonder if your apostrophes are correct.  see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alter.asp) - I think they belong only around values

Comment: that makes sense to me, maybe the problem was in my knowledge of concatenate string variables. I will check when i return home from work. Thank you <3.

Comment: it was like u said, the ' ' is only for values not for names

Answer (score -1):

I do not know what you are trying to do, but you should NEVER let a user insert unfiltered text into a SQL query.
Imagine a user will type in the textbox the following text: `abc'; DROP TABLE itemTable;` - this is a security weakness called 'SQL Injection'.

Comment: i'm the only person who is gonna use this application. its ment to help me reducing some efforts in my day work. so there is no problem with the security + if i'm gonna let someone else use it, i can make sure that the main Names cannot be inside the textbox as a solution

Comment: OK. I'm not sure but I think you must add the word `COLUMN` before the column name, and also you do not need to use quots, so try this: `ALTER TABLE itemsTable ADD COLUMN " + textbox1.text + " VARCHAR(50) NULL;`

Comment: yep, the problem might be because i used the ' '. When i return home i will try it. Thank you

Comment: The issue of SQL injection is correct but other than that: This is not an answer and the word COLUMN is not needed. See my link!

Comment: please explain answer according to guidelines